# Neo4J APOC A* and Dijkstra Conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm currently using built-in dijkstra for Neo4J path finding using conditions (see-below).

**CYPHER**

```
PROFILE MATCH path = shortestpath((s:Node {UID: 73946372})-[Road*]->(e:Node {UID: 2383529534}))
WHERE ALL(x in relationships(path) WHERE x.LG_6 > 0 || x.C60 > 100)
WITH path, reduce(s = 0, r IN relationships(path) | s + r.Length) AS dist
RETURN path, dist LIMIT 1
```

However, I would like to know if it's possible to do the same with APOC and have conditions such as x.LG_6 > 2000 AND x.C60> 0. The cypher below is what I currently use but they have no conditions.

**APOC A***

```
PROFILE MATCH (s:Node {UID: 73946372}),(e:Node {UID: 2383529534})
CALL apoc.algo.aStar(s, e, 'Road', 'Length','Latitude','Longitude') YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight LIMIT 1
```

**APOC Dijkstra**

```
PROFILE MATCH (s:Node {UID: 73946372}),(e:Node {UID: 2383529534})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(s, e, 'Road', 'Length') YIELD path AS path, weight AS weight
RETURN path, weight LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to use APOC algorithms with such conditions ?

Comment: Nope, but still need it :(

Comment: Why is your first query calculating `dist`? It is never used.

Comment: Fixed. It was provided from an original example/documentation and assumed it was used in the 'reduce' to get the shortest path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Cypher function `shortestPath` does not use a relationship weight property to calculate the shortest path -- it only uses the length of the path (i.e., the number of relationships in the path).

   So the `dist` returned by your first query is misleading, since it is NOT what the `shortestPath` function looked at to determine the `path` result. This is also why your first query's result may not match the result of another algorithm that *does* use a weight property.
2. The [Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/) plugin contains [path-finding algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/labs-algorithms/pathfinding/) that support (via [Cypher projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/projected-graph-model/cypher-projection/)) what you want, and they can use a weight property. The `stream` variants of those methods return the native ID of each node in the resulting path, along with the total weight up to that point in the path. Currently, this plugin is only supported by neo4j version 3.5.14 and below.

For example:

#### A*

```
MATCH (s:Node {UID: 73946372}), (e:Node {UID: 2383529534})
CALL algo.shortestPath.astar.stream(s, e, null, 'Latitude', 'Longitude', {
  nodeQuery: 'MATCH (p:Node) RETURN id(p) as id',
  relationshipQuery: 'MATCH (a:Node)-[x:Road]->(b:Node) WHERE x.LG_6 > 0 || x.C60 > 100 RETURN id(a) AS source, id(b) AS target, x.Length AS weight',
  graph: 'cypher'
}) YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN nodeId,cost
```

#### Dijkstra

```
MATCH (s:Node {UID: 73946372}), (e:Node {UID: 2383529534})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(s, e, null, {
  nodeQuery: 'MATCH (p:Node) RETURN id(p) as id',      
  relationshipQuery: 'MATCH (a:Node)-[x:Road]->(b:Node) WHERE x.LG_6 > 0 || x.C60 > 100 RETURN id(a) AS source, id(b) AS target, x.Length AS weight',
  graph: 'cypher'
}) YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN nodeId, cost
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go in the morning.

Comment: I'm getting the following error at the space after MATCH:
Failed to invoke procedure `algo.shortestPath.astar.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse projection: expected letter, digit, or underscore (at position 5):
MATCH (a:Node)-[x:Road]->(b:Node) WHERE x.LG_6 > 0 RETURN id(a) AS source, id(b) AS target, x.Length AS weight

Comment: I have fixed that by adding the `graph: 'cypher'` parameter to my `A*` code. That is needed to use Cypher projection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, got further. Now I get a the following with no details, same with Dijkstra: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.shortestPath.astar.stream`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException: Unexpected end of input: expected whitespace, CYPHER options, EXPLAIN, PROFILE or Query (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))

Comment: OK. I added the `nodeQuery` parameters as well. (The queries only display those errors if there is actual data, so I am flying blind :-)).

Comment: Yay! Is there a way to also return the edges/nodes and their properties as well? Or at least the relationship ids.

Comment: Those procedures do not return the relationships (or their IDs), so you'd have to use the returned `nodeIds` to do additional `MATCH`es to get the relationships. If you cannot figure that out, you can ask another question. I have to go to bed :-).